# DataBinding in Windows Phone is blocking UI threading

Tags: image, data-binding, listbox, windows-phone-8

I am trying to do the standard - bind a list of data (including images) received from REST API calls in a very quick and smooth manner - a paradox in itself.  I have 2 service calls that each take about 2 seconds to complete so I can async/await those, but based on the data returned, I then build other lists (observableCollection) in memory and bind them back to ListBox's in the page.

Problems:

1. This actual binding seems to lock up the UI thread, how can I asynchronously load my page - listBox by listBox (or even item by item) in a lazy fashion?  I'd like to put a placeholder image in place and when finally bound, the placeholder is replaced by the bound image.  Any ideas?  Frameworks?  Tools?
2. When binding the actual images, the other data in my DataTemplate, actually jumps around the screen while the Image is rendered.  It looks terrible...  I'd like to be able to, at the very least, bind the image first and then the other controls in the dataTemplate after?  Anything that would make it appear a bit smoother would help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your problem in (2) will be solved with the placeholder image (assuming that it is the same size as the downloaded images).

I suspect that your "lock up" problem in (1) is that you are calling `Wait` or `Result` on a `Task` returned by an `async` method. In many cases, this results in a deadlock, as I explain [in a recent MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) and [on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

I think what you really want is a way to start a `Task` and get a data-binding notification when it completes. I've developed a [set of types (`TaskCompletionNotifier`)](https://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Source/Nito.AsyncEx%20%28NET4,%20Win8,%20SL4,%20WP75%29/TaskCompletionNotifier.cs) that helps out in this situation. Check out the end of [my blog post on `async` properties](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-3-properties.html) for a sample. You may also be interested in [my blog post on `async` constructors](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html).

Answer (score 0):

(1) If the list of items is large, binding them all at once will cause some stalling on the UI thread. One fix is to add the items a few at a time and pause so that the UI thread can get a new frame to the compositor before continuing.

```cs
public async void AddObjects(List<object> objects)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < objects.Count; i++)
    {
        _myObservableCollection.Add(objects[i]);
        if(i % 10 == 0) await Task.Delay(100);
    }
}
```

(2) You should set a fixed width and height on the images in the DataTemplate, so that it does not change as the image is actually downloaded. Alternately, if you can fetch the width and height from your service in the API calls, bind the image width/height to those values before it gets downloaded.